# Control flow not reaching a line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple function to submit a POST request to an ASP.NET MVC url.

The control does not even reach the last line of code where the form is submitted. Please help. Here's the function I invoke at the click of a hyperlink.

```
function submitNewAccountInfo() {
  debugger;
  var newAccountInfo =
  {
    FullName: $("#NewUserAccountInfo_FullName").val(),
    Email: $("#NewUserAccountInfo_Email").val(),
    PasswordHash: md5($("#NewUserAccountInfo_Password").val())
  };

  debugger;
  // The control does not even come here. What am I doing wrong?
  $("#frmCreateNewAccount").submit(newAccountInfo);
}

<a href="#" onclick = "submitNewAccountInfo();">Create my account</a>
```

Comment: Is there any error printed in the console? Perhaps `Uncaught ReferenceError: submitNewAccountInfo is not defined`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. There were a couple of issues with my code:

I wasn't using jQuery to bind/wire up event handlers with events. As a result, the short-cut `onclick` that I took was attaching an *event handler* and not an *event listener*.

This meant that I had to handle all browser incompatibilities and also get hold of the `event` object to *prevent its default behavior*, none of which I was doing and all of which jQuery makes it very easy to do.

I changed my code to bind/wire up an event listener using jQuery and my code is now working. Here's the working code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lnkCreateMyAccount").click(submitNewAccountInfo);
});

function submitNewAccountInfo(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var newAccountInfo =
        {
            FullName: $("#NewUserAccountInfo_FullName").val(),
            Email: $("#NewUserAccountInfo_Email").val(),
            PasswordHash: $("#NewUserAccountInfo_Password").val()
        };

    $("#frmCreateNewAccount").submit(newAccountInfo);
}
```